# $H_n(M,M-{x}) \cong H_n(M,M-U)$ where U is open?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $M$ be a manifold and $U$ one of its charts. If $x$ is a point in $U$, then
$H_n(M,M-{x}) \cong H_n(M,M-U)$?

The professor in the following [video](https://youtu.be/5qmaCABucgI?t=2949) says it is because of excision, but I can't see how.

Here is a similar version found on page 233 of Hatcher's book.
[image]

Comment: What text? What is $n$ exactly?

Comment: In any case, as you wrote this the result is not true: if $U$ is not connected then $H(M,M-U)$ is more complicated…

Comment: Hi, I first saw this in this video https://youtu.be/5qmaCABucgI?t=2949. Then I also found something very similar on page 233 of Hatcher. I have posted a screenshot of the text.

Comment: Notice that in Hatcher B is a ball, not a chart...

Comment: I know it is a different version in hatcher. But I first saw the version I wrote down at 49:00 of the video.  So is the one written down by the professor wrong?

Comment: As I wrote, if $U$ is not connected, then the homology of $(M,M-U)$ is more complicated.

Comment: If U is connected, then is it true? I will greatly appreciate it if you can give me a hint on how to prove this.

Comment: I am new to this stuff but my first guess would be a simply connected $U$ which I think does the job?

Comment: You have still not answered the second question in my initial comment.

Comment: Suppose that $U$ is a *ball* containing $x$. Consider the map from the long exact sequences corresponding to the pair $(M,M-U)$ to the long exact sequence of the pair $(M,M-x)$ induced by the identity map of $M$: in it you have maps that look like $H_p(M)\to H_p(M)$ which are identities, and maps which look like $H_p(M-U)\to H_p(M-x)$ which are isomorphisms because the inclusionb $M-U\to M-x$ is a homotopy equivalence. It follows from the five-lemma that the other maps are isomorphisms, and that is the one one want.

Comment: $U$ is "one of its charts" here, so it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$ by definition. In particular it is connected, even contractible.

Comment: What is true by excision is that $H_i(M, M - x) \cong H_i(U, U - x)$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thank you so much! So basically, we require that the inclusion $M - U$ $\to$ $M - x$ to be a homotopy equivalence. I was trying to show homotopy equivalence of the pairs between $(M,M-x)$ and $(M,M-U)$, and didn't remember to use the five-lemma to by pass it. Btw, the n in my original question was the dimension of the manifold. But I guess it holds for all n in general.

Comment: @freakish, well, that depends on the definition of chart. Most people will not add that condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let $M$ be a manifold and $U$ one of its charts. If $x$ is a point in $U$, then
> $H_n(M,M-\{x\}) \cong H_n(M,M-U)$.

Here you should correctly say "$U$ is the domain of a chart" because a chart on a (topological) $n$-manifold $M$ is a homeomorphism $\phi : U \to U'$ from an open subset $U \subset M$ to an open subset $U' \subset \mathbb R^n$.

Let us first make precise what is meant by  $H_n(M,M-\{x\}) \cong H_n(M,M-U)$. Actually we want to find open $U \subset M$ such that the inclusion of pairs $i : (M,M - U) \to (M,M-\{x\})$ induces an isomorphism in all homology groups
$$i_* : H_k(M,M-U) \to H_k(M,M-\{x\}) .$$
It should be clear that **excision** cannot provide such an isomorphism. We can excise any subspace $S \subset  M-\{x\}$ such that $ \overline S \subset \operatorname{int} (M-\{x\}) = M-\{x\}$, but this produces an inclusion  of pairs $i' : (M -S ,M-(S \cup \{x\})) \to (M,M-\{x\})$ which does not help us.

Consider the following commutative diagram in which the upper and lower row are parts of the long exact sequences of the pairs $(M.M-U)$ and $(M, M-\{x\})$ and $j : M-U \to M-\{x\}$ denotes inclusion:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
H_{k+1}(M-U) @>{}>> H_{n+1}(M) @>{}>> H_{k+1}(M,M-U) @>{}>> H_{k}(M-U) @>{}>> H_{k}(M) @>{}>> H_{k}(M,M-U)\\
@V{j_*}VV @V{id}VV @V{i_*}VV @V{j_*}VV  @V{id}VV @V{i_*}VV \\
H_{k+1}(M-\{x\}) @>{}>> H_{k+1}(M) @>{}>> H_{k+1}(M,M-\{x\}) @>{}>> H_{k}(M-U) @>{}>> H_{k}(M) @>{}>> H_{k}(M,M-\{x\}) \end{CD}

The five lemma tells us that $i_* : H_k(M,M-U) \to H_k(M,M-\{x\})$ is an isomorphism for all $k$ iff $j_* : H_k(M-U) \to H_k(M-\{x\})$ is an isomorphism for all $k$.

Is that true for *any* $U$ being the domain of a chart? As an example take $M = \mathbb R^n$ with $n > 0$ and $U = M - \{\xi\}$ for some $\xi \in M$. This is the domain of the identity chart on $U$. But $$H_k(M-U) = H_k(\{\xi\}) = \begin{cases} 0 & k > 0 \\ \mathbb Z & k = 0 \end{cases}$$
$$H_k(\mathbb R^n-\{x\}) \cong H_k(S^{n-1}) = \begin{cases} 0 & k \ne 0, n-1 \\ \mathbb Z & n > 1 :  k =  0, n-1 \\ \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z &  n = 1 : k = 0 \end{cases}$$

This shows that it is false in general. But what can be done? Let us do it as Hatcher and consider the following  special open $U \subset M$:

For any chart $\phi : V \to V'$ let $B'$ be any closed Euclidean ball contained in $V'$. Its interior $U'$ is an open Euclidean ball. Then $U = \phi^{-1}(U)$ does the job because $M-U$ is a strong deformation retract of $M-\{x\}$ for all $x \in U$. In fact, let $B = \phi^{-1}(B')$. Then $B-\{x\}$ strongly deformation retracts to $\partial B = \phi^{-1}(\partial B')$.